# OpenSSL zero an existing allocated array

Tags: c, openssl, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have an existing dynamically allocated array for example:

```
unsigned char *c =NULL
for(int i=0; i<10;i++){
  //receiveKeySizeFromNetwork receives a key size from the network
  int key_size = receiveKeySizeFromNetwork(); 
  unsigned char *c = OPENSSL_realloc(c, key_zise*sizeof(unsigned char));
  receiveKeyFromTheNetwork(c, key_size);
  //Further logic
}
```

And I use `c` as a temporary array to receive from multiple hosts their keys. As fas as I've seen at OPENSSL v1.1.0 there is the function `OPENSSL_clear_realloc` that safely handles realocation of memory, which at my system's installed OPENSSL does not exist.

Thus I thought to use existing OPENSSL functions and perform my own safe memore reallocation. So I want to ask:

1. Is good idea to do so?
2. How I can zero an existing `unsigned char` buffer using OPENSSL v1.0.2 - delivered libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know for 1. but for 2. you can use the `OPENSSL_cleanse` function defined as:

```
 void OPENSSL_cleanse(void *ptr, size_t len);
```

And is the same in v1.0.2 and in v1.1.0 of OPENSSL. In my case using OPENSSL v1.0.2 I make my own safe allocation function tailored to handle byte-sized arrays:

```
unsigned char* safeRealloc(unsigned char *value, int oldsize, int newsize){
  if(oldsize < 0 || newsize <= 0) {
    safeFree(value);
    return NULL;
  }

  if(oldsize > 0 ) OPENSSL_cleanse(value,oldsize);
  return OPENSSL_realloc((void *)value,newsize);
}
```